# android camera orientation SurfaceView

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I have made a customize video recorder using surfaceview everything is going fine just the problem is whenever i change the switch to landscape mode my recorder still captures the video is portrait mode rather than this i want that whenever while recording is going on if i switches  the mode it should automatically switch the mode of recording.

this is my code

```
package rishabh.agarwal.holmes.video1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AndroidVideoCapture extends AppCompatActivity{

private Camera myCamera;
private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

Button myButton;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    recording = false;

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Get Camera for preview
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    if(myCamera == null){
        Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this,
                "Fail to get Camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
    FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
}

Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
        = new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(recording){
            // stop recording and release camera
            mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
    recording=false;
            Log.e("aaa","step1");
            myButton.setText("START");

            //Exit after saved
           // finish();
        }else{

            //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
            releaseCamera();

            if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
                Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this,
                        "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }

            mediaRecorder.start();
            recording = true;
            myButton.setText("STOP");
        }
    }};

private Camera getCameraInstance(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();

         c.setDisplayOrientation(90);// attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    myCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(3600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(500000000); // Set max file size 5M

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);


    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mediaRecorder != null) {
        mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
        mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mediaRecorder = null;
        myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (myCamera != null){
        myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        myCamera = null;
    }
}

public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
                               int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

}
 Someone please suggest me the necessary changes in my code so that i may get the correct output
 here are some of the images i am [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkzuq.jpg)attaching of the problem
[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYHHw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setCameraDisplayOrientation() 
{        
     if (mCamera == null)
     {
         Log.d(TAG,"setCameraDisplayOrientation - camera null");
         return;             
     }

     Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
     Camera.getCameraInfo(CAM_ID, info);

     WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
     int rotation = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

     int degrees = 0;

     switch (rotation) 
     {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) 
     {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me where to place this function ?

Comment: Have you considered using the standard method thats provided in the API doc, which you can call on surfaceChanged? You could store the degrees in a global variable to later use when saving the picture. Also could do a simple null checker on your camera variable, so you don't create it again in surfaceCreated.

Answer (score 0):

you Can Also Use this code

```
    @Override
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

    // determine our orientation based on sensor response
    int lastOrientation = mOrientation;

    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();                                        

    if (display.getOrientation() == Surface.ROTATION_0) {   // landscape oriented devices
        if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {                         
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
            }
        } else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
            }                       
        } else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;
            }                       
        } else if (orientation <135 && orientation > 45) { 
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
            }                       
        }                       
    } else {  // portrait oriented devices
        if (orientation >= 315 || orientation < 45) {
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL) {                          
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_NORMAL;
            }
        } else if (orientation < 315 && orientation >= 225) {
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL) {
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_NORMAL;
            }                       
        } else if (orientation < 225 && orientation >= 135) {
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED) {
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT_INVERTED;
            }                       
        } else if (orientation <135 && orientation > 45) { 
            if (mOrientation != ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED) {
                mOrientation = ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE_INVERTED;
            }                       
        }
    }

    if (lastOrientation != mOrientation) {
        changeRotation(mOrientation, lastOrientation);
    }
}
```